# Protractor-Identifying elements?

Tags: protractor

I am  trying to identify an element in the following code to  automate the input  of a text field using protractor, any comments are much appreciated & here is the code,

```
<input ng-disabled="!cell.editable"
    name="99286434"
    class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid ng-valid-required ng-touched" 
    ng-class="{'is-required':cell.field.required &amp;&amp; !xxx.xxx.data}" 
    ng-model="xxx.xxx.xxx" 
    ng-change="dataChanged(cell)" 
    ng-required="cell.field.required" 
    ng-trim="false" 
    type="text">
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: where is the code and what is the problem?

Comment: @VishalAggarwal Thanks for reaching out, The above html code is related to particular  input  field for a text, and i want to track it like element.by.id.. or something  like that tried element by name but still the issue is there...

Answer (score 1):

You can use [by.model](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBy.prototype.model)

`element(by.model('xxx.xxx.xxx'))`

or

```
element(by.css('input[ng-model="xxx.xxx.xxx"]'))
```

If both can't work,  check the element inside a frame, add some sleep/wait prior to find the element.

Comment: thanks for replying, how ever it could not be able track that element here is the codevar EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf($('#some id')), 50000).then(function () {                               browser.driver.findElement(by.model('xxx.xxx.xxx')).click();

Comment: Did you replace the `xxx.xxx.xxx` to your real ng-model value.

Comment: what error reported when use my answer? and did you check the element to find is not inside frame?

Comment: Hi yong sorry for late response, I am still unabled to tack down that by model, how ever i tried the xpaths and was able to track 'em ,cheers